# Does Quran say space travel is impossible?

Tags: moon

Salam brothers and sisters, I'm a new revert so i'm sorry if this is a stupid question but I saw a clip on twitter of Mr.Daniel Haqiqatjou saying that moon landing was essentially faked and that humans can't develop the means of space travel.
and then I came across this verse 55:33
يٰمَعۡشَرَ الۡجِنِّ وَالۡاِنۡسِ اِنِ اسۡتَطَعۡتُمۡ اَنۡ تَنۡفُذُوۡا مِنۡ اَقۡطَارِ السَّمٰوٰتِ وَالۡاَرۡضِ فَانْفُذُوۡا​ؕ لَا تَنۡفُذُوۡنَ اِلَّا بِسُلۡطٰنٍ​ۚ‏
i want to know is it the correct interpretation of this that space travel is not possible?

Comment: here is the link to the stream timestamped where he talks about it https://www.youtube.com/live/vZymuO_lUms?feature=share&t=13256

Comment: Good question, I never looked at that verse from this angle.

Comment: Daniel Haqiqatjou is a creationist, believes the Smithsonian is covering up evidence for the existence of giant humans, and believes the moon-landing is fake. Take anything he says with a grain of salt

Comment: hmm thanx for your advice i will keep in mind

Answer (score 0):

No. This verse is about the Day of Judgement and means that none can escape it. The fault in the interpretation given by you is that some arbitrary and wrong definition is being assigned to 'earth' and 'heavens'. If we were to interpret the verse like this then air travel should also not be possible, while it is know that it is possible.

Comment: it says "the heavens AND the earth" not "the heavens OR the earth" (which is how you seem to have interpreted it) so 'maybe' it refers to leaving both the heavens AND the earth at the same time, not just one or the other.   This makes a lot more sense than interpreting "heavens and the earth" as a metaphor for the last hour which really is a dizzying logic leap in my humble opinion

Comment: @Maalik It is not a metaphor, it is literal, but it is about the day of judgement and this is what is mentioned in Tafsirs, and it is also what is apparent from the context.

Comment: thanx a lot I read the verses preceding it and I understand the context now